# I am unable to click on any element which is inside a frame tag in Test Cafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am able to login to my application but after that unable to perform any action because all elements are inside the frame tag.
The approaches I have tried:

1. Selector(() =>{return
   document.getElementById("frameId").contentDocument.getElementById("#ele")});
2. t.switchTo("frameID");
   var ele = Selector("#ele");
   await t.click(ele);
3. browser.switchToFrame('#outerFrame');
4. const y=await ClientFunction(() => window.location.pathname)()
   await t.switchToWindow(f => f.url.pathname === y)

**please do let us know any workaround to access the element inside the frame tag**

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to click an element inside an iframe is to use the `switchToIframe` function. Please refer to the following article for more details: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402681/reference/test-api/testcontroller/switchtoiframe

Comment: yes but we are not using iframe in our project. All the elements are inside frame tag.

Comment: TestCafe does not allow switching to the `frame` elements. Frame is a deprecated feature and it's not recommended to use it. You can read about `frame` in the following article [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame)